# Entity in context in JayData is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jaydata

I wrote this code to use WebSQL with JayData in Chrome:

```
 $data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Department",
 {
     Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
     Name: { type: "string", required: true }
 });

$data.EntityContext.extend("$org.types.OrgContext", {
    Department: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Department }
});

$org.context = new $org.types.OrgContext({ name: "WebSQL", databaseName:"Organization",
    dbCreation: $data.storageProviders.sqLite.DbCreationType.DropTableIfChanged
});

var department = new $org.types.Department({ Name: 'Department1' });
$org.context.Department.add(department);
$org.context.saveChanges();
```

but the problem is that, in $org.context.Department.add(department); line,  ***"Department"*** is undefined.What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was: the $data WebSQL provider name is: `webSql`, this way the example worked perfectly. Plus of course the onReady handler was needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the onReady function of the context. When you try to add the new Department entity to the entity set the context is not yet initialized. Use is like this:

```
$org.context.onReady(function(db){
    var department = new $org.types.Department({ Name: 'Department1' });
    db.Department.add(department);
    db.saveChanges(function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

It's recommended to always use the callback functions because everything is asynchronous and you don't know that the process is ready outside of the callback.

Comment: $data.ODataProvider supports direct invocation without the need for the onReady handler, but it's always the safest to use it, as it can not hurt :).